# Change SharePoint scope at runtime

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007, scope

I have a requirement where based on a users SharePoint group, there search should be a specific scope. My question is, is it even possible to change the SharePoint search box to use search a particular scope at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint search from search box is based upon query string what ever text is passed in query string parameter "s" is treated as scope if you replace "s" by "cs" it becomes contextual scope. i would suggest to create a custom web part may be using c# or you can use editor web part.